# JWT updating payload from node.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, jwt, satellizer

I am using Satellizer in my MEAN Stack webapp to login users. The satellizer module uses JSON Web Tokens.

The token is created in:

```
var jwt = require('jwt-simple');

function createJWT(user) {
  var payload = {
    sub: user._id,
    user: {
            displayName: user.displayName,
            email: user.email,
            admin: user.admin
        },
    iat: moment().unix(),
    exp: moment().add(2, 'hours').unix()
  };
  return jwt.encode(payload, config.TOKEN_SECRET);
}

app.post('/auth/login', function(req, res) {
  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, '+password', function(err, user) {
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(401).send({ message: 'Wrong email and/or password' });
    }
    user.comparePassword(req.body.password, function(err, isMatch) {
      if (!isMatch) {
        return res.status(401).send({ message: 'Wrong email and/or password' });
      }
      res.send({ token: createJWT(user) });
    });
  });
});
```

The thing is that later in a function, I need to update the user key inside the payload object.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Basically token looks like string. when you change payload then your token is changed (new string). You can't change token / payload without changing string. You can create new one based on previous.

Remember to return new token to client application.